# How do I know which drools rule is running now?

Tags: drools

For example, I am load a lot of drools rules to run, how do I know which drools rule now is running? So I can know find out the rule

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about the right hand side of the rules, you'll want to use an [AgendaEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/event/rule/AgendaEventListener.html). This is an interface which defines a listener that you can create that watches the Event Lifecycle. For more information about the event model, please refer to the [Drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.54.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_event_model).

The easiest way to do this would be to extend either `DefaultAgendaEventListener` or `DebugAgendaEventListener`. Both of these classes implement all of the interface methods. The Default listener implements each method as a "no-op", so you can override just the methods you care about. The Debug listener implements each method with a logging statement, logging the `toString()` of the triggering event to INFO. If you're just learning about the Drools lifecycle, hooking up the various Debug listeners is a great way to watch and learn how rules and events process in rules.

(Also the cool thing about listeners is that they allow you to put breakpoints in the "when" clause that trigger when specific conditions are met -- eg when a rule match is created. In general I find that listeners are a great debugging tool because they allow you to put breakpoints in methods that trigger when different parts of the Drools lifecycle occur.)

Anyway, what you'll want to do is create an event listener and then pay attention to one or more of these specific events:

- BeforeMatchFired
- AfterMatchFired
- MatchCreated

Which events to pay attention to depend on where you think the issue is.

If you think the issue is in the "when" clause (left-hand side, LHS), the `MatchCreated` event is what is triggered when Drools evaluates the LHS and decides that this rule is valid for firing based on the input data. It is then put on, effectively, a priority queue based on salience. When the rule is the highest priority on the queue, it is picked up for firing -- at this point the `BeforeMatchFired` event is triggered; note that this is *before* the "then" clause (right-hand side, RHS) is evaluated. Then Drools will actually do the work on the RHS, and once it finishes, trigger the `AfterMatchFired`.

Things get a little more complicated when your rules do things like updates/retracts/etc -- you'll start having to consider potential match cancellations when Drools re-evaluates the LHS and decides that a rule is no longer valid to be fired per the facts in working memory. But in general, these are the tools you'll want to start with.

The way I would traditionally identify long-running rules would be to start timing within the `BeforeMatchFired` and to stop timing in the `AfterMatchFired`, and then log the resulting rule execution time. Note that you want to be careful here to log the execution of the *current* rule, tracking it by name; if your rule extends another rule you might find that your execution flow goes `BeforeMatchFired(Child) -> BeforeMatchFired(Parent) -> AfterMatchFired(Parent) -> AfterMatchFired(Child)`, so if you're naively stopping a shared timer you might start having issues. My preferred way of doing this is by tracking timers by rule name in thread local or even a thread-safe map implementation, but you can go whichever route you'd like.

---

If you're using a very new version of Drools (7.41+), there is a new library called `drools-metric` which you can use to identify slow rules. I haven't personally used this library yet because the newest versions of Drools have started introducing non-backwards-compatible changes in minor releases, but this is an option as well.

You can read more about `drools-metric` in the official documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#performance-tuning-drl-ref_drl-rules) (you'll need to scroll down a bit.) There's some tuning you'll need to do because the module only logs instances where the thresholds are exceeded. The docs that I've linked to include the Maven dependency you'll need to import, along with information about configuration, and some examples of the output and how to understand what it's telling you.

Comment: Thank you. How do we know which expression/condition within a rule execution time is too long?

Comment: On the RHS, that's not something you can figure out with a Drools logger. I've used an aspected logger to track method call timings to do this. The listeners above can just tell you how long it takes to run the whole RHS; once you've identified the long running "then" clauses you can further investigate those individual method calls using normal Java-based methods.

Comment: I am exclude one Condition/Expression in each Drools run to test it, so I know which Condition/Expression taking longer time, although this sounds not-productive

Comment: Right that's not productive. You should use your standard Java analytics/instrumentation tools to identify the long-running methods.